# Multiple recipients using Mandrill and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mandrill

I'm using ruby to send transactional emails via Mandrill.
As part of my product, I want to be able to send the same email to two recipients and have them see each other's email address.
(Like an introduction mail between two people).

So I filled he "to" field with both emails, and on my dashboard is seems that both are sent.
But unfortunately only one of the recipients receive the mail and the details of the second recipient is hidden.

In conclusion, I have two problems:

1. Only one recipient gets the mail
2. Hidden details of the second recipient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I approached Mandrill support and this is what they replied:

> If you'd like to enable this option globally for all of the messages you send, then you'll want to ensure that you have the
>   "Expose The List Of Recipients When Sending To Multiple Addresses"
>   option enabled in your Sending Defaults.
>
> If, instead of making that change globally, you'd like to enable it
>   for individual messages, you'll want to use the
>   X-MC-PreserveRecipients (SMTP header), or the preserve_recipients (API
>   parameter), and set it to 'true'.
>
> If you set this option to true, we'll expose the list of recipients to
>   each other as you would see happen when sending mail from a typical
>   email client program.

It worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you want both recipients to be able to see each other, you can pass an array of e-mails in the `to` option.

If you do *not* want either of them to see each other, you can, in a loop over the users, send said e-mail.

If using `ActionMailer` it can be done like so:

```
mail(
  to: ['person1@gmail.com', 'person2@gmail.com']
)
```

Or in a loop:

```
[user1, user2].each do |user|
  UserMailer.some_email(user).deliver_now
end

mail(
  to: user.email
)
```

Post your code, I have an idea of what your problem may be.  Remember that a method in an `ActionMailer` class should only return `mail()` and must not be looped over inside of that method.

tldr: do everything unrelated to e-mail outside mailer, pass through necessary data as params to the method, end method with `mail()` call.

Comment: Yeah I got that part.. actually the mystery was solved by Mandrill support team.